# Get element content if text exists next to it

Tags: php, regex

I have this HTML in `$string`:

```
$string = '<p>random</p>
<a href="">Test 1</a> (target1)
<br>
<a href="">Test 2</a>  (target1)
<br>
<a href="">Test 3</a> (skip)
// etc
';
```

And I have a few terms in `$array`:

```
$array = array(
    '(target1)',
    '(target2)'
);
```

How can I search through `$string` to find all terms in `$array` and grab the content of the `<a>` tag that precedes it?

So I end up with the following results:

```
$results = array(
    array(
        'text' => 'Test 1',
        'needle' => 'target1'
    ),
    array(
        'text' => 'Test 2',
        'needle' => 'target1'
    )
);
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
// Assuming your HTML as $str, your terms as $terms
$results = [];

foreach ($terms as $t) {

    // Get content of <a> tag preceeding the term
    preg_match_all('/<a ?.*>(.*)<\/a>\s+' . preg_quote($t) . '/', $str, $matches);

    //Then insert into your result array
    foreach ($matches[1] as $m) {
        $results[] = [
            'text'   => $m,
            'needle' => $t
        ];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
// echo '<pre>' . print_r($results, true) . '</pre>';
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => Test 1
            [needle] => (target1)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => Test 2
            [needle] => (target1)
        )

)
```

---

See also: [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

Comment: Why would you use regex vs. a DOM parser?

Comment: @JayBlanchard OP took note of your comment and posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931648/get-content-of-tag-if-term-exists-after-it-using-domdocument). I don't know how to do with a DOM parser but I share a solution with regex. I'm not saying this is better.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Please feel free to demonstrate how you would do it using dom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931648/get-content-of-tag-if-term-exists-after-it-using-domdocument). I couldn't pull it off which is why I went the regex route.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an answer using javascript, but php can do the same thing.

You can search through the array 1 string at a time, and finish once no results are found and you have reached the end of your array.

```
target1Match = s.match(/<.+?>(.+?)<\/.+?> *\(target1\)/);
// target1Match is now [<a href="">Test 1</a> (target1), Test 1]
target1Match = target1Match[1];

target2Match = s.match(/<.+?>(.+?)<\/.+?> *\(target2\)/);
// target1Match is now [<a href="">Test 2</a> (target2), Test 2]
target2Match = target2Match[1];
```

You build the regex using variables for "target1 and 2"

matching multiple targets and specific tag

```
s.match(/<a.+?>(.+?)<\/a> *\((target1|target2)\)/);
```

Comment: Interesting. Can I add an "or" statement, so the regex is in one line. Something like: `/<.+?>(.+?)<\/.+?> *\(target1|target2\)/` etc... Also, can I adjust the regex so it only targets `<a>` because currently, it matches with any tag: https://regex101.com/r/9waqFR/1

Comment: You can use OR, but then you need to add a new capture group, so you would know which of the targets matched. You can match a specific tag like this:
s.match(/<a.+?>(.+?)<\/a> *\((target1|target2)\)/);

Comment: Why would you use regex vs. a DOM parser?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the JayBlanchard camp.  Here's a solution that rightly uses DomDocument & Xpath with a dynamically generated query to target `<a>` tags that are immediately followed by text that contains one of the qualifying needles.

For the sample needles, this is the generated query:

```
//a[following-sibling::text()[1][contains(.,'(target1)') or contains(.,'(target2)')]]
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Pr4qP))

```
$html = '<p>random</p>
<a href="">Test 1</a> (skip)
<br>
<a href="">Test 2</a> (target1)
<br>
<a href="">Test 3</a>  (target1)
<br>
<a href="">Test 4</a> (skip)
<br>
<a href="">Test 5</a>  (target2)
<br>
<a href="">Test 6</a> (skip)
';

$needles = [
    '(target1)',
    '(target2)'
];

$contains = array_reduce($needles, function($carry, $needle) {
    return $carry .= ($carry !== null ? ' or ' : '') . "contains(.,'$needle')";
});

$matches = [];

$dom=new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//a[following-sibling::text()[1][$contains]]") as $node) {
    $matches[] = ["text" => $node->nodeValue, "needle" => trim($node->nextSibling->nodeValue)];
}
var_export($matches);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'text' => 'Test 2',
    'needle' => '(target1)',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'text' => 'Test 3',
    'needle' => '(target1)',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'text' => 'Test 5',
    'needle' => '(target2)',
  ),
)
```