# Get content of tag if term exists after it using domdocument

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

Have this `$html`:

```
$html = '<p>random</p>
<a href="">Test 1</a> (target1)
<br>
<a href="">Test 2</a>  (target1)
<br>
<a href="">Test 3</a> (skip)
// etc
';
```

And I have a few terms in `$array`:

```
$array = array(
    '(target1)',
    '(target2)'
);
```

How can I skim through `$html` using domdocument to find all terms in `$array` and grab the content of the `<a>` tag that precedes it?

So I end up with the following results:

```
$results = array(
    array(
        'text' => 'Test 1',
        'needle' => 'target1'
    ),
    array(
        'text' => 'Test 2',
        'needle' => 'target1'
    )
);
```

### What I've tried so far

With the following approach, I have managed to grab the content of all `<a>` tags in `$html`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query('//a'); 
$el_array = array();
if ($elements->length > 0) {
    foreach($elements as $n) {
        $node = trim(strip_tags($n->nodeValue));
        if (!empty($node)) {
            $el_array[] = $node;
        }
    }
    if (!empty($el_array) && is_array($el_array)) {
    print_r($el_array);
    }
}
```

But I have not found a way to grab the target terms so that I can check if we have a match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dynamic xpath query with contains and following-sibling.

The xpath expression will be:

```
//a/following-sibling::text()[contains(., '(target1)') or contains(., '(target2)')]
```

For example:

```
$array = array(
    '(target1)',
    '(target2)'
);

$contains =  implode(" or ", array_map(function($x) {
    return "contains(., '$x')";
}, $array));

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//a/following-sibling::text()[$contains]");
$results = [];

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $results[] = [$element->previousSibling->nodeValue, trim($element->nodeValue)];
}

print_r($results);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test 1
            [1] => (target1)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test 2
            [1] => (target2)
        )

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/7BiUN)

Comment: This one is pretty next level.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the parsed dom, everytime you meet and anchor *save*  his value, then check whether a node value is inside your array (`target1,target2`), if true, store inside `$result` the current node and the old anchor text.

```
<?php
    $html = '<p>random</p>
    <a href="">Test 1</a> (target1)
    <br>
    <a href="">Test 2</a>  (target1)
    <br>
    <a href="">Test 3</a> (skip)
    // etc
    ';

    $array = array(
        '(target1)',
        '(target2)'
    );

    $result = array();
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $test = showDOMNode($doc,$array);
    print_r($result);

    function showDOMNode(DOMNode $domNode,$array,$oldval=false) {
        global  $result;
        foreach ($domNode->childNodes as $node){
            $nodename = $node->nodeName;
            $nodevalue = $node->nodeValue;
            if($nodename == "a"){
                $oldval = $nodevalue;
            }
            if(in_array(trim ($nodevalue),$array)){
                $tmp = array(
                    "text"=> $oldval,
                    "needle" =>$nodevalue
                    );
               $result[] = $tmp;
            }
            if($node->hasChildNodes()) {
                showDOMNode($node,$array,$oldval);
            }
        }    
    }
```

It outputs :

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [text] => Test 1 [needle] => (target1) ) 
[1] => Array ( [text] => Test 2 [needle] => (target1) ) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks! But why are you doing a global on $result?

Comment: Because is outside of the scope, and the function is recourisive, if you prefer you can pass everytime the array and merge it before call the function again

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - didn't see that you'r solution required domdocument :/

---

I think this should do it:

```
$html = '
<p>random</p>
<a href="page1.php">Test 1</a> (target1)
<br>
<a href="page2.htm">Test 2</a>  (target1)
<br>
<a href="page3.html">Test 3</a> (skip)
// etc
';

$array = array(
    '(target1)',
    '(target2)'
);

#Explode HTML into new lines, to run through each line

$lines  = explode("\n", $html);

foreach ($lines as $line){

    #Find pattern from $array, and if match, use preg_match_all to find the text in the a-tag
    if(str_replace($array, '', $line) != $line){
        preg_match_all('/<a href=\".*\">(.*?)<\/a>/s', $line, $matches);

        print_r($matches[1]);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Test 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => Test 2
)
```

Comment: This isn't a **domdocument** approach. Thanks for the alternative approach though.

Comment: Just realised that.. :/